# I want to create a condition from 2 character columns of one data set and apply it other

Tags: r, dplyr

Here is my source data set df

| col1 | colB |
| --- | --- |
| 343 | fd |
| 456 | df |
| 236 | gh |
| 129 | tr |
| 560 | te |

Col 1 is my disease code and col is my disease name.
I have new data set where I want Disease codes to reflect the disease name in source data

new data set df1

| id | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 343 | fd |
| 2 | 236 |  |
| 3 | 129 |  |
| 4 | 560 |  |

.......

So here for id 1 we have disease code as '343' so the col2 should have disease name as 'fd'.
I have more than 400 ids in my data.
Can anyone help me with this?

Here is the code I tried but didnt work

```
df1 %>% case_when(col2 = case_when(df$col1 = df$col1 ~ de$DESCRIPTION ))
```

essential I want col 2(disease names) in my new data set "df1" corresponding to col1 same as those in source data set.

Comment: `left_join(df1, df, by = "col1")`

Comment: @Phil I used that. In df1 I had 634 observation with non unique disease codes, and df has 426 IDs with disease codes being non unique. After using this I get around 140000 observations

Comment: `left_join(df1, distinct(df, col1, col2), by = "col1")`

Answer (score 0):

@Phil's suggested `left_join()` should work, I assume that your data looks more like this with mutiple descriptions per id or with duplicated entries

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

df <- tribble(
  ~desease_code, ~desease_name,
  343, "fd",
  456, "df",
  236, "gh",
  129, "tr",
  129, "tr",
  560, "te",
  560, "tef",
  560, "teg",
  560, "teh"
) 


df1 <- tibble(id = 1:5, desease_code = c(
  343,
  456,
  236,
  129,
  560
))
df1 |>
  left_join(df, by = "desease_code")
```

One potential remedy would be to use `distinct(.keep_all=TRUE)` before joining the datasets, e.g.

```
df1 |>
  left_join(df |> distinct(.keep_all = TRUE), by = "desease_code")
```